# DATEDIFF in dd,hh,mm,ss in Impala

Tags: sql, impala

I want a query that shows a time difference in hours and minutes in Impala. Or in SQL?

How can I do this?

start 2017-11-29 19:45:00 - end 2017-11-29 21:30:00

Comment: show your attempts as well.

Comment: I am trying the regular SQL statements but it gives me an error that it does not find a column "year, minutes etc.". For now I am just brainstorming queries like SELECT TIMEDIFF('official_end', 'official_start') from game  ---- or SELECT DATEDIFF(year, 'official_end', 'official_start') FROM game.

Comment: Start with something simple, like just the minutes and gradually build up to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

So DATEDIFF gives you the difference between two dates in DAYS. This can be converted to hours by multiplying by 24. The remainder of this answer is then minutes if multiplied by 60.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I still haven't figured it out yet what the syntax is on how to put it in, in the query.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to do it? I've got the days working with the following: select datediff (official_start,official_end) AS Hours from game

Comment: I tried hour after datediff (datediff(hour,start,end) , but it recognizes it as a column.

Comment: I have been working on this today and have found a solution but I'm still coding it. I'll update my original answer when I've finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
secondsDiff = timestamp2 - timestamp1
minutes_diff = secondsDiff / 60
hours_diff = secondsDiff / (60*60)
```